# Formatar String "28122016" para data "2016-12-28"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sei que é uma pergunta bem simples, mais já pesquisei bastante e não estou encontrando uma solução simples.
Preciso criar um função que receba uma data no formato `"28122016"` e converta ela para `"2016-12-28"`. Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A melhor solução é usar as funções prontas do pacote [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html). Exemplo:

```
from datetime import datetime
d = datetime.strptime('28122016', '%d%m%Y')
print(d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Veja funcionando [no Ideone](http://ideone.com/fje7BD).

Mas, se preferir (e se for coisa pontual e rápida mesmo), você também pode fazer manualmente:

```
data = '28122016'

dia = int(data[:2])
mes = int(data[2:4])
ano = int(data[4:])

print('{:4d}-{:2d}-{:2d}'.format(ano, mes, dia))
```

Veja funcionando [no Ideone](http://ideone.com/Sbh892).

Comment: Excelente Luiz, desconhecia

Comment: Uma pergunta Luiz, no seu segundo exemplo, porquê `'{:4d}-{:2d}-{:2d}'`? Porque não `'{}-{}-{}'` neste caso?

Comment: @Miguel Só pra deixar claro que dá pra formatar o inteiro com o tamanho ("*padding*") desejado. Mesmo motivo pelo qual eu fiz o casting pra `int` anteriormente: minha teimosa didática. rs Também não precisava.

Comment: Exato, era o que eu pensava, mas podia ser por causa de outro motivo que não sabia. Obagdo

Answer (score 10):

## Solução

Se tiver a certeza que o formato a ser tratado sempre será `ddmmyyyy`, você pode criar uma função da seguinte forma:

```
my_date = lambda d: "{}-{}-{}".format(d[4:8], d[2:4], d[0:2])
```

Para usá-la, basta invocá-la da seguinte forma: `my_date("28122016")`. O resultado deverá ser `2016-12-28`.

> Você pode ver o código funcionando [aqui](https://repl.it/FSqE/0), basta pressionar o botão `Run` para executar o script.

## Explicação

A solução faz uso do método `format` presente em objetos do tipo `string` nativamente. Através de `{}` é definido o novo formato do texto, substituindo cada `{}` pelo respectivo valor passado ao método.

Neste caso, o primeiro `{}` será substituído pelo valor de `d[4:8]`, em que `d` é o valor passado pelo parâmetro ao invocar a função. Como a string pode ser vista como um vetor de caracteres, ao utilizar `d[4:8]`, estamos acessando os caracteres nas posições de 4 à 8, exclusive, ou seja, 4, 5, 6 e 7, que representará o ano da data. Já o segundo `{}` será substituído pelo valor de `d[2:4]`, que representará o mês, e o terceiro `{}` pelo valor de `d[0:2]`, que representará o dia.

Caso necessite de operações mais complexas que esta, você pode utilizar a versão nomeada de parâmetros do método `format`, como subsequente:

```
my_date = lambda d: "{year}-{month}-{day}".format(day = d[0:2], month = d[2:4], year = d[4:8])
```

O resultado será exatamente o mesmo, mas com o formato mais legível para humanos.

> Para mais informações sobre o método `format`, clique [aqui](https://pyformat.info/). Documentação oficial sobre strings: [aqui](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html).

Comment: Apesar de ser basicamente a mesma solução já proposta, leva o meu +1 pelo esforço de explicar passo a passo e pela indicação da versão nomeada de parâmetros no `format`. :)

Comment: Pois é, não vi que haviam respondido enquanto eu formulava a resposta kkk

Comment: Relaxa. Conhecimento nunca é demais e a sua resposta ficou mesmo boa. :)

Comment: eu fiz dessa forma que você explicou e tive o retorno de saida assim <function RegC100.__init__.<locals>.convData.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x0000014175576EA0>

Comment: @RicardoGomes, isso porquê você não invocou my_date como uma função. Tente executar my_date("20161228").

Comment: foi isso mesmo o problema, estava colocando ele dentro de uma função e dessa função fazendo o my_date não entendi muito bem o porque o my_date se tornou uma função mais deu certo

Comment: @RicardoGomes, my_date é uma função porque a defini utilizando a instrução lambda, que em python serve para criar funções anônimas. Neste caso, cria-se uma função anônima e é atribuída ao objeto my_date (lembrando que em python tudo é objeto), por isso necessita-se a invocação de my_date como função. Poderia definir my_date como uma função normalmente, através da instrução def, que o resultado seria exatamente o mesmo. É somente uma questão de costume utilizar lambda para funções simples, de apenas uma linha de comando.